# Error while passing two arguments to scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: scipy-optimize

I am trying to find a local minimum of a 2 variables function, but I am struggling with the syntax of scipy.optimize.minimize, as it looks like it is not accepting how I am passing the initial point:

```
import scipy.optimize as sop
function = lambda x,y: 2*(x**2)*(y**2)+3*x*x+2*x+4*y+7
p0 = [0,0]
min_ = sop.minimize (function,x0=p0)
```

Resulting in the following error:

`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

passing the values directly to the function, such as:

```
function(0,0)
```

works without issue.

But, if I pass an array or a tuple, it results in the same error:

```
x0 = (0,0)
function(x0)
```

`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`

Help appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a function of two scalar variables, but scipy.optimize.minimize expects a function of **one (typically non-scalar) variable**. So you only need to rewrite your objective function:

```py
def function(xy):
    # unpack the vector xy into its components x and y
    x, y = xy
    return 2*(x**2)*(y**2)+3*x*x+2*x+4*y+7

p0 = [0, 0]
min_ = sop.minimize(function,x0=p0)
```